# How to correctly pass POST params to an asp.NET http handler from PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have an http handler (asp.NET 4.0) to process something:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request;
    var userId = request["username"];
    var password = request["password"];
    var otherParam = request["otherparam"]
    ...
    // Process using userId, password and otherparam
    ...
}
```

I am trying to POST data to there by this PHP script:

```
function do_post_request($url, $params)
{
    $query = http_build_query ($params);    
    $contextData = array ( 
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                                "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                    'content'=> $query );   
    $context = stream_context_create (array('http' => $contextData));   
    return  file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);
}

$url = "http://localhost:33614/dosomething";
$params  = array('username'=>'xyz', 'password'=>'123456', 'otherparam'=>'Sample from PHP');
$result = do_post_request($turl,$params);
var_dump($result);
```

The problem is, I am getting the `username` parameter in the http handler, but other two parameters are found `null`. I found those parameters as `amp;password` and `amp;otherparam`. I tried sending from python, c#, java etc but never found this problem.

How can I get the params? By the way, I don't have much knowledge of PHP.

Comment: What is the value for your `arg_separator.output` configuration?

Comment: How to get that? I don't have much PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amp;` equals `&` after escaping for html, you got php escaping the characters or asp

Try to force it on php by doing:

```
http_build_query($params, '', '&');
```

instead of just `http_build_query($params)`

Comment: Hmm, I think this is working. I'll accept this answer after some testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your POST body get's html-encoded, thus the original string `username=xyz&password=123456&otherparam=Sample%20from%20PHP` get's html-encoded to `username=xyz&amp;amp;password=123456&amp;amp;otherparam=...`

Your problem is that `&` get's encoded to `&amp;` when sent to the server. You can do a little debug to see if the `http_build_query()` is the one that double encodes, or if `stream_context_create()` is responsible for that.